# How to download or attach pdf file after output - mpdf

Tags: php, pdf

I want mpdf to generate pdf file upon AJAX request by user. Everything runs fine but the response do not open as pdf.

In the RESPONSE under NETWORK i see something like this:

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.280 841.890]
/TrimBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
/Resources 2 0 R
/Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> 
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 382>>
stream
x­TËNÃ0ôÙ_1G8à®8¯HP©·Ò [¨j+µêï³ô!q°ãÝ]ÛØpBj9
ç3eÛ l`¼VÚùß_#=
ðäZQg?¬d/Ú¤ÒãÁSX`©Â`"IÙÌá$<2R¬dËÑx¦±:6Qâ ß?ØÙ¼9ãÌÑscåbxØ{dB
8Æ&*1\TfuÅ¸ZØråDÊ¾G±f
.°%À9K½(²l%÷*vâKÅBÌ/Éì«úÝÜ" yàöV¹<LCnmj|êQâ3³Æ¡½¿¹Åk^N¾Ît¥[WfI9e'%]a0Ú¡X ÇÉ]m¨3o³ÐõºtÐfÐíÎMahjðØn6¦YO´D~¯¬¿¶\B Ì)m¿üu.¿@u^ÿç~î«ª3ªÃ³ßL
~L¬
```

Please guide that how do I let `mpdf` attach the file generated to the browser so that the user can download it??

this is my code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/pdf'); 
require('../../../../core/inc/connect.php');
require('../func.php');
require('mpdf.php');

    //generate sign up codes as pdf file
if (isset($_POST['codes'])) {
$content = array();
foreach ($_POST['codes'] as $key => $value) {
    $content[] = mpdfContent($value,'Unused');
}
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML("<div>".(implode($content))."<div style='clear:both;'></div></div>");
$mpdf->Output();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add as well the following header in your script:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment")
```

This would download the document.

Comment: It didn't work.  it still return the file a string in console

Comment: I mean the response

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to set any headers by yourself. This is handled by MPDF if the destination is I (inline) or D (force download). Check the MPDF docs or the sources to see what headers are sent. [MPDF manual](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html) The headers should be shown in the network console as well.

What is your intend calling the download code via AJAX? Normally you'd either request some JSON oder HTML via AJAX to update the view state of the current page. If the AJAX is triggered by a link, try to link to your PHP file directly without using AJAX as I'm not sure if the download headers are interpreted when doing an AJAX call

Comment: in my application under the admin section I have numerous PIN CODES used as signup code. An an may need to select a some many or little code to be generated into pdf and then eventually print it. ...so with the AJAX will send the particular PINS the admin may want to generate and print. because I want to it as pdf am using mpdf to write rich html as pdf... so with the AJAX request I watn the generated pdf open in maybe in new tab on the browser without puting the file on the server.. This is what I want to do with AJAX

Comment: Then why not use <a target="_blank" href="..">PDF</a>?